# Spark Scala println requires a collect()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera

Just getting started with Spark and Scala.  We've installed Spark 2 on our dev cloudera hadoop cluster, and I'm using spark2-shell.  I'm going through a book to learn some basics.  It's examples show println(foo) working without doing a collect, but that's not working for me:

```
scala> val numbers = sc.parallelize(10 to 50 by 10)
numbers: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[9] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> numbers.collect().foreach(println)
10                                                                              
20
30
40
50

scala> numbers.foreach(x => println(x))

scala>
```

As you can see, nothing prints unless I do a collect().

What's going on, is the book wrong, or is something funny with my spark/scala/config?

Version Info:

```
Spark version 2.0.0.cloudera2
Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111)
```

Comment: What environment are you running in?  If you are running on a cluster, the  foreach without a collect first runs on the cluster and not your local machine.

Comment: Thanks, guessing that's the issue.  Our DEV hadoop cluster running spark has a few data nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the correct behaviour you experience, the code passed to `numbers.foreach` will be executed on the different nodes, but the output won't be collected and returned to the driver.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  The book was assuming you'd be running it on a simple local VM with everything running there.  Maybe that's my issue, our DEV hadoop cluster has a few data nodes.